# How to make button disable with true or false with property binding and without binding?

Tags: angular

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';  
@Component({  
    selector: 'my-app',  
    template: `<div>  
    <button [disabled]='isDisabled'>click</button>  
                     </div>`  
})  
export class AppComponent {  
isDisabled= false;  
}
```

Above angular code making button enable but below code without any data binding  not enabling button regardless of true or false. please help me to understand what is wrong.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';  
@Component({  
    selector: 'my-app',  
    template: `<div>  
    <button disabled=false>Disable me</button>  
                     </div>`  
})  
export class AppComponent {  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is difference between `[disabled]="isDisabled"` and `disabled="false"`

- `[disabled]="isDisabled"` - you are changing property directly in the DOM through Angular, that's why you should pass true or false
- `disabled="false"` - it's just simple html attribute, you can pass whatever you want even `disabled="1"`, it will be counted as true anyway, if you want to enable button you should delete this attribute from html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the square brackets, it will be treated as disabled, which is the intended use of this attribute:

```
<button disabled>Disabled</button>
```

You would have to add/remove the attribute to enable/disable the button with Javascript:

```
<button>Enabled</button>
```

Since you are in Angular, it's best to use square brackets on disabled and assign a boolean to it:

```
<button [disabled]="true">Disabled</button>
<button [disabled]="false">Enabled</button>
```